# Declaration of the date parameter with the automatic addition of the month in the sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I work in SQL Developer by Oracle. I have a longer query where I have multiple dates in some conditions but every dates based on a start_date and only difference between them are months and days.
I want to declare only one date e.g. start_date='2021-06-01' and afterwards in query where I have condition like COLUMN_DATE BETWEEN DATE '2021-08-01' AND DATE '2021-08-31' only add months (in that example add 2 months in query and get the results from whole August/ e.g. 2021-08-01=start_date+(2months)). Is it possible to get results like that without entering each value separately? Below is my sample code.

```sql
Def start_date='2021-06-01' 

Select
1column,
2column,
(case when exist(select 1
                from table2
                where between date '2021-08-01' and date '2021-08-31')
                then 1 else 0 end) as 3column
from table1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ADD_MONTHS` and pass in your substitution variable:

```
Select column1,
       column2,
       case
       when exist(select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.date_column >= ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(&start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 2)
                  and   t2.date_column <  ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(&start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 3)
                 )
       then 1
       else 0
       end as column3
from   table1;
```

*Note: In Oracle, a `DATE` always has a time component (the user interface you are using may chose not to show the time component though, but it will still be there) so if you want a month's worth of data and you compare to `DATE '2021-08-31'` then you will miss any values between `2021-08-31 00:00:01` and `2021-08-31 23:59:59`.*